# Restoring 10.6.7 wallpapers

Tags: snow-leopard

This may sound a bit silly and I hope it's not off-topic, but... I'm looking for a specific wallpaper that was present in OS X 10.6.7 (an Ansel Adams-style black-and-white landscape with the sun hidden behind some very remarkable clouds). It is no longer present in OS X Lion.

Strangely, it is also not a part of the [OS X 10.6 wallpapers pack.](http://download.chip.eu/en/MacOSX-Snow-Leopard-Wallpaper-Pack_5721758.html)

Is there a comprehensive resource from which old OS X wallpapers can be accessed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its the mountains in black and white with the sun behind clouds.. It's in this pack: http://www.redmondpie.com/download-os-x-snow-leopard-wallpapers/

Comment: +1, good find. Is that one called "Winter Sunrise?" Also liked the Mojave and Sea Mist pictures.